# Where are Overwatch key bindings stored?

Tags: overwatch

Where are the Overwatch key bindings stored?

All I was able to find is `C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Overwatch\Settings\Overwatch\settings_v0.ini`, but those are only graphical/sound settings. I need keybindings, like <kbd>W</kbd> for "Walk forward".

I understand they can be in unreadable hex format, but still - where is the file, which saves all those settings? It should be somewhere.

Comment: You don't want in-game one? Just the file?

Comment: @n_palum, I what the place where the settings are stored, what do you mean by "in-game one"?

Comment: Like when you're in the game and you can change your key bindings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found multiple sources stating that keybindings are stored server side - meaning you won't be able to get that file without Blizzard sending you it (which they likely won't).

- [Reddit One](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4oav3d/config_file_to_adjust_keybinds/)
- [Reddit Two](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4zaokd/where_are_keybindings_stored/)

[One source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/3su3oa/is_there_a_config_file/cx0s1fy/) believes its in a folder called `casc` under `Overwatch/data/casc/`.  From there, there is a folder called `config`, but the files might be in an unreadable format.  The image below is from the linked source:

[image: File Structure]

Comment: Well. The believe of the third source has no ground, since when you change settings the casc dirrectory doesn't change. I guess it is server side storage, then. I didn't thought about this option.